# Go Package installed but not able to import

Tags: go, glide-golang

Not able to import the gorilla/mux package even though it is installed. i used the command "go get github.com/gorilla/mux" to install the package which installed the package under the pkg directory as per the GOPATH as below.

C:\Users*\go;C:\Users*\goProject

But as go Looks for the packages in the src directory, i moved the Gorilla package to the folder "C:\Users*\goProject\src" folder and removed the go.mod file. After that i initialized the package bu executing the command "go mod init" but still import fails.

Please find below the snap shot . Can anyone please help with this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVInI.png)

Solution for the above issue

Comment: Do not post images of text.

Comment: You **must** use modules and `go get` your external dependencies. Consult go.dev/doc for details.

Comment: Did you run **go mod init main** and then **go mod tidy**?

Comment: GOPATH and modules are competing ways to manage dependencies. GOPATH is obsolete. Do not use it for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your project is small and only has one package(few files in the same folder which are in the same scope) please follow these steps:

1. create an empty folder for your project
2. run this command: **go mod init main** instead of main you can put your project name or URL
3. add your files and run **go mod tidy**, at this step the packages you use(for your case **gorrila/mux**) are downloaded and ready to use
4. now you can run your app by **go run main**

for more advanced projects, you can follow 1 and 2 step and then create folders for your desing and have multiple **main** packages in separate folders and create multiple executable binaries, if you need more details you are welcome to ask